# Как настроить права к разделам для группы пользователей в битрикс24

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Всем привет!

Появилась необходимость создать группу пользователей, которой будет доступен только один раздел "CRM", все остальные разделы не должны попадать в область видимости пользователя.
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Битрикс позволяет настроить доступ только к инфоблокам или каталогам. Поэтому для таких пользователей можно создать каталог, в котором выводить только список элементов нужного раздела. И дать права на правку. А в админку прав не давать.